# Replace pattern in Regex using variables and strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble doing the following search and replace:

```
// Consider this string - Note that it may be much more complicated, with many more matches
string output = "\"$type\": \"SomeType\",";

// The variable to search and replace - In this case is set to "SomeType"
string myType = "SomeType";

// The non-working regex
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\"\$type\"\:\s\"" + myType + @"\",", "NewType");
```

I would expect the following output:

```
"$type": "NewType",
```

instead of:

```
"$type": "SomeType",
```

I think there are 2 problems here, but I cannot figure out the syntax. One is the use of the string "type", the other one is that I am not using capture groups so that only myType gets replaced by "NewType" in the output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```cs
output = Regex.Replace(output, $@"(?<=""\$type"":\s""){Regex.Escape(myType)}(?="",)", "NewType");
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/bJB86k).

NOTES:

- `"` must be escaped with another `"` in a verbatim string literal
- Escape the variables inside regex patterns
- Use lookarounds to wrap the pattern parts you need to keep after substitution.

The resulting regex looks like `(?<="\$type":\s")NewType(?=",)` and matches

- `(?<="\$type":\s")` - a location that is immediately preceded with `"$type":` a whitespace and `"`
- `NewType` - some text
- `(?=",)` - a location that is immediately followed with `",`.

Comment: Ouha, much trickier than I thought, thanks a lot!

Comment: What if myType was defined in the following line of the string, but had to be inserted as previously done? Can I do something of the sort: Regex.Replace(g, $@"(?<=""\$type"":\s""){"AString"}("",\s*\n\s*""Name"":\s""{myVariable}?="",)", myVariable, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: @stackMeUp You may use any amount of variables in the regex pattern.

Comment: Thank, I figured it out :-)